# PostgreSQL: How to differentiate stored procedures and table-valued functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, information-schema

Question:

In Microsoft SQL Server, there are stored procedures, and there are table-valued functions.

The difference is, from a stored procedure, I cannot do further selects, while from a table-valued function, I can.

e.g.

`SELECT * FROM sp_whatever WHERE xxx` is illegal
while
`SELECT * FROM TVF_whatever WHERE xxx` is perfectly legal

Now my question:

In PostgreSQL, when I look at `information_schema.routines`, how can I differentiate table valued functions, and procedures ?

Is there a difference at all ?

And in general, how can I differentiate functions and procedures in PostgreSQL?

I mean theoretically, on SQL-server, one can differentiate them like this:
Table valued function: `information_schema.data_type = 'table'`
stored procedures: `information_schema.data_type IS NULL`
functions: `information_schema.data_type != 'table' AND information_schema.data_type IS NOT NULL`

How is this done in Postgres?

Theoretically, a stored procedure has return type void, but since a stored procedure can also return a table, there is no way to differentiate between tvf and stored precedure - assuming there *is* a difference.

So my question could also be formulated:
In PostGreSQL, how do I create a table-valued function, and how do I create a stored procedure (1 example each). 

I'm interested in the difference in the return type between the two, if there is any.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL doesn't have real stored procedures, just user defined functions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo() RETURNS TABLE(bar INT, baz TEXT) ...

CREATE FUNCTION bar() RETURNS BOOLEAN ...
```

Check for datatype "record":

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.routines WHERE data_type = 'record';
```

Comment: So, you are saying, in pgsql, a "stored procedure" that returns a select is completely equivalent to a table_valued function ? Or is there a way to define the return type so it remains a table, but cannot be used in further selects & joins, just like the result of a stored procedure ?

Comment: You can always use the result of a function in other queries and/or functions, no problem at all.

Comment: @Quandary The latter point you describe, where it returns a result that cannot be (directly) consumed by other procs/functions, can be achieved by returning a refcursor. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html . The caller then `FETCH`es from the cursor to get the result. Honestly, though, you should usually just use table-returning functions, ie functions that return `SETOF something`.

Comment: @Quandary As for equivalence, it's more that there *are no stored procedures in PostgreSQL*. Everything is done with SQL-callable functions. The only real limitations this imposes is that you can't directly return multiple result sets (though you can via refcursors), and you can't begin/commit transactions within functions.

Comment: `CREATE FUNCTION foo() RETURNS TABLE(bar INT)` does not yield `data_type = 'record'`. It yields `data_type = 'int'`. So it's not that simple...